# How to round up a time value by on hour?

Tags: python, time

I need to subtract two strings which are representations of times and them round up by one hour. I've tried to use `datetime.replace` method by `total` is `timedelta` object and I can't call that method. How can I round up `total`?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = '23:14'
end = '03:34'
total = datetime.strptime(end,'%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
```

Comment: what do you mean round up ? you mean difference in hours ? I am guessing start and end timestamps are of the same day and hence end >= start always (which doesn't seem to be the case in your example).
to get time difference in seconds, you could do total.total_seconds()
to get time difference in minutes, you could do total.total_seconds() / 60
to get time difference in hours, you could do total.total_seconds() / 3600

Comment: I meant that if the outcome is 4:15 it will round to 5:00

Comment: You have to add one day 'total += timedelta(days=1)' when you go over midnight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timedelta object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times.
class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
All arguments are optional and default to 0. Arguments may be ints, longs, or floats, and may be positive or negative.

Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally. 
Instance methods:
timedelta.total_seconds()
Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration
using this we can calculate the difference in hour as below

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = '23:14'
end = '03:34'
total = datetime.strptime(end,'%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
round((total.total_seconds())/3600)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer: what have you changed and why?

Comment: total is object from which we can extract days, seconds etc. in this code first extracted the difference in seconds then converted it back to hour. Round is used to round up nearest hour

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer, not to the comment section

Comment: To calculate time duration timedelta.total_seconds() must be used instead of timedelta.seconds. (-1 day and 15600 seconds) !=  (15600 seconds). It is the internal representation.

Comment: Correct seconds just returns only that fraction which is less than a day. Amending the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one day to guarantee it will always work in the future. The property total.seconds is not the total duration. It is the wrong shortcut.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.strptime('23:14','%H:%M')
end = datetime.strptime('03:34', '%H:%M')
print('   start', start)

total = end - start  # wrong

print('1. end  ', end)
print('   total', total)
print('   seconds', total.seconds)
print('   total_seconds', total.total_seconds())

if end < start: # correct
    end += timedelta(days=1)
total = end - start

print('2. end  ', end)
print('   total', total)
print('   seconds', total.seconds)
print('   total_seconds', total.total_seconds())

rounded_up_hours = round((total.total_seconds() + 1800.)/3600.)

print('rounded_up_hours', rounded_up_hours)
```

Output:

```
   start 1900-01-01 23:14:00
1. end   1900-01-01 03:34:00
   total -1 day, 4:20:00
   seconds 15600
   total_seconds -70800.0
2. end   1900-01-02 03:34:00
   total 4:20:00
   seconds 15600
   total_seconds 15600.0
rounded_up_hours 5
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer: what have you changed and why?